# Benefits of Converting List<String> to HashSet<String> Java

Tags: java, performance, big-o

So I have a list of strings that I need to instantiate once every time a service is called. Is it worth it to convert the `List<String>` to a `HashSet<String>` and then check if the String is in the hashSet?

eg.

```
HashSet<String> services = new HashSet<String>((List<String>) services);
```

I know checking for the string in the list is O(n) and the check for the string in the hashSet is O(1). I think the conversion is probably O(n).

Is there a performance benefit to the recast if I am not searching over the list more than a few times?

Comment: It's doubtful you'll see a measurable performance improvement, especially if, as you mention, you're only searching the structure a few times.

Comment: Since you'd have to visit every element in the set anyway to add it to the set, you may as well just call contains on the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no benefit to switching. Your Bio O performance analysis is correct.

Comment: If I was doing the check multiple times there would be a benefit right? The more times the greater benefit to the switch?

Comment: Searching n times in the list is n * O(n) searching n times in HashSet is n * O(1) so it depends how often the data are searched. They two solutions are not the same. It is necessary to know how many elements are present in the list. and how many reaserch on the list are done.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO The OP said he's "not searching over the list more than a few times" which I take to mean a small insignificant number. Also note that he would need to convert the `List` to a `Set` as well which is `O(n)` itself.

Answer (score 1):

`List` and `Set` are not the same thing:

- A list is ordered. A set is not.
- A list can contains the same object multiple times. The set don't allow duplications.

So the first questions you need to ask yourself are:

- I need duplication in the list?
- I need a special order in the list?

If the answer to both questions is no it is better to use an HashSet instead of the List. This will guarantee better performances retrieving elements.

If you can't change the List to an HashSet but you need to duplicate data structures it is necessary to check better your code to see if the set creation time is slower than the time gained for retrieving elements